# Rotation of plane along a line

Tags: 3d

The plabe $x+2y+3z=7$ is rotated about the line where it cut yz plane by an angle m . In the new position the plane contains the point (-1,0,2)  . We have to find cos m.

My try

Equation of yz plane is x=0

equation of rotated plane would be $(k+1)x+2y+3z=7$ .

subtituting the values I got k=-1

the angle would be

$\cos m =\frac{7}{\sqrt{14}\sqrt{5}}$ .

Comment: When you put $(-1,0,2)$ in the plane, you get $k = -2$ and hence $\cos m = \frac{6}{7}$

Comment: @Muralidharan thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plane $x + 2y + 3 z = 7$ cuts $yz$ plane: Set $x = 0$ to get the line of intersection of the two planes:
$2y +3z = 7$.

Rotating the original plane about this straight line gives:

$ax + 2y + 3 z = 7$ .

(Any rotated plane cuts the $yz$ plane  in the line $2y + 3z = 7 $ which leaves $a$ as a parameter for the rotated plane).

The rotated plane passes through $(-1,0,2) $:

$a(-1) + 3(2) = 7$; which gives$ a = -1$.

Unit normal of the original plane: $ n(1) = (1/√14) (1,2,3)$.

Unit normal of rotated plane $n(2) = (1/√14) (-1,2,3)$.

With $\gamma$ the angle between them:

$Cos (\gamma)$=

$n(1)$•$n(2)$ =

$1/(14) 12 = 12/14 = 6/7$ .

( Dot Product )

Comments welcome.